# Jquery accordion not removingClass and not swapping its Expand text for Collapse

Tags: jquery, height, accordion

Thanks to @ifaour for a lot of his help! This script includes:

- Jquery accordion using unordered lists.
- Active and Inactive states with toggling bullet arrow images
- Expand All / Collapse All that swaps its text.
- Equal height columns that expand and collapse when the accordion expands and collapses

You can view a demo here http://jsbin.com/ucobo3/24/

```
(function($) {
$.fn.equalHeights = function(minHeight, maxHeight) {
tallest = (minHeight) ? minHeight : 0;
this.each(function() {
if($(this).height() > tallest) {
tallest = $(this).height();
}
});
if((maxHeight) && tallest > maxHeight) tallest = maxHeight;
return this.each(function() {
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 6.0) { $(this).height(tallest); }
$(this).css('min-height', tallest + 'px').css('overflow', 'auto');
});
}
})(jQuery);

jQuery.fn.initMenu = function() {
  var isCollapsed = true; // default value
  var collapseAll = 'Collapse All';
  var expandAll = 'Expand All';

  $('.swap').click(function() {
    if(!isCollapsed)
    {
      $('ul.menu li ul').slideUp('normal');
      $('ul.menu li').removeClass('active');
      $(this).text(expandAll);

      isCollapsed = true;
    } else {
      $('ul.menu li ul').slideDown('normal');
      $('ul.menu li').addClass('active');
      $(this).text(collapseAll);
      isCollapsed = false;
    }
    return false;
  });

  return this.each(function(){
    var theMenu = $(this).get(0);
    $('.acitem', this).hide();
    $('li.expand > .acitem', this).show();
    $('li.expand > .acitem', this).prev().addClass('active');
    $('li a', this).click(
    function(e) {
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      var theElement = $(this).next();
      var parent = this.parentNode.parentNode;
      if($(parent).hasClass('noaccordion')) {
        if(theElement[0] === undefined) {
          window.location.href = this.href;
        }
        $(theElement).slideToggle('normal', function() {
          if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
          }
          else {
            $(this).prev().parent().removeClass('active');
          }    
        });
        return false;
      }
      else {
        if(theElement.hasClass('acitem') && theElement.is(':visible')) {
          if($(parent).hasClass('collapsible')) {
            $('.acitem:visible', parent).first().slideUp('normal',
            function() {
              $(this).prev().parent().removeClass('active');
            }
          );
            return false;  
          }
          return false;
        }
        if(theElement.hasClass('acitem') && !theElement.is(':visible')) {         
          $('.acitem:visible', parent).first().slideUp('normal', function() {
            $(this).prev().parent().removeClass('active');
          });
          theElement.slideDown('normal', function() {
            $(this).prev().parent().addClass('active');
          });
          return false;
        }


      }
    }
  );

  });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu').initMenu();          
  $('.column').equalHeights();
});
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my try:

```
jQuery.fn.initMenu = function() {
    var isCollapsed = true; // default value
    var collapseAll = 'Collapse All';
    var expandAll = 'Expand All';

    $('.swap').click(function() {
        if(!isCollapsed)
        {
            $('ul.menu li ul').slideToggle('normal');
            $('ul.menu li a').removeClass('active');
            $(this).text(expandAll);
            isCollapsed = true;
        } else {
            $('ul.menu li ul').slideToggle('normal');
            $('ul.menu li a').addClass('active');
            $(this).text(collapseAll);
            isCollapsed = false;
        }
        return false;
    });

    return this.each(function(){
        var theMenu = $(this).get(0);
        $('.acitem', this).hide();
        $('li.expand > .acitem', this).show();
        $('li.expand > .acitem', this).prev().addClass('active');
        $('li a', this).click(
        function(e) {
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            var theElement = $(this).next();
            var parent = this.parentNode.parentNode;
            if($(parent).hasClass('noaccordion')) {
                if(theElement[0] === undefined) {
                    window.location.href = this.href;
                }
                $(theElement).slideToggle('normal', function() {
                    if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
                        $(this).addClass('active');
                    }
                    else {
                        $(this).prev().removeClass('active');
                    }    
                });
                return false;
            }
            else {
                if(theElement.hasClass('acitem') && theElement.is(':visible')) {
                    if($(parent).hasClass('collapsible')) {
                        $('.acitem:visible', parent).first().slideUp('normal',
                        function() {
                            $(this).prev().removeClass('active');
                        }
                    );
                        return false;  
                    }
                    return false;
                }
                if(theElement.hasClass('acitem') && !theElement.is(':visible')) {         
                    $('.acitem:visible', parent).first().slideUp('normal', function() {
                        $(this).prev().removeClass('active');
                    });
                    theElement.slideDown('normal', function() {
                        $(this).prev().addClass('active');
                    });
                    return false;
                }


            }
        }
    );

    });
};

$(document).ready(function() {$('.menu').initMenu();});
```

[Example link](http://jsbin.com/ucobo3/13).
Since the `.swap` link is common for all, no need to have it inside the `each` loop.

Comment: this looks really good and i truly appreciate you going to the extra effort. thanks ifaour

Comment: @ifaour - now that i've seen what happens when they all expand, some menus, such as those under section 3, don't contain sub links. i'm thinking the bullets should only show an active state when a menu contains sub links. what do you think?

Comment: @ifaour - again. thank you. you really helped me with my project with your contribution.

Comment: @ifaour - ok. i added "slideUp" and "slideDown" instead of "toggle", which resolved an unwanted behavior. after i click "test 1" under Section 1 and click "Expand All", it will no longer collapse my "test 1". See here: http://www.jsbin.com/ucobo3/15

Comment: Ah! true..sorry I didn't notice, was trying to solve the "expand all/collapse all" issue :-)

Comment: @ifaour - and you did! i could not have done it without you! take care man

Comment: @ifaour - i have a follow up question for this link: http://www.jsbin.com/ucobo3/15 when you click on "Test 1", it will expand and apply the "active" class to the "A" tags. I would actually prefer this to be applied to the "LI" tags instead. would you be able to help me with this code change? (The expand all can be ignored as I was able to do the expand all piece myself) This is just when the Test 1 is clicked individually.

Comment: @Evan: I've [edited](http://jsbin.com/ucobo3/17) your code and replaced the whole `acitem` toggle thing with ***one*** line, I don't know if this is what you want..and I didn't touch your `noaccordion` but you can get the idea

Comment: @ifaour - thank you. This is what I needed. I should be able to modify this further if I need the noaccordion, I can modify that, too. This is perfect.

Comment: @ifaour - The menu I'm building has 2 stylish borders wrapped around it, so I added a plugin that calculates "equalHeights" for both the columns. The issue using this equal height is as accordions expand and collapse, there's overflow on the column borders shown here: http://jsbin.com/ucobo3/21/. So, I added .css("overflow","auto") to the plugin here: http://jsbin.com/ucobo3/20/, which adds ugly scrollbars. The better solution is to slip the equalHeight into the accordion, so when the accordion expands and collapses, the column style would do the same.

Comment: @ifaour - check it out. i'm close! http://jsbin.com/ucobo3/24/ i now have both columns at equal height when the page loads and the border class will now expand instead of overflow when the accordions expand. the only challenge i can't figure out is how to get BOTH columns to expand equally. do you have an idea? i hope i'm not offending you by involving you like this. you've been a huge help!

Comment: @ifaour - agian, thank you for that tip! do you have a paypal account? i need to send you some cash for beer i owe you for all your help!

Comment: @Evan: well, I usually use my friend's account in Canada since our *so-called* country is not supported for reasons this is not the proper place to discuss :-) anyway, you are welcome to contact me on my e-mail (in my profile) to get the paypal account. AND you are welcome

Comment: @Evan: You are aware that this plugin needs a lot of work and optimization and can only be used on very specific scenarios and not meant to be published for public use on it's current state, right?

Comment: @ifaour - i sent you a friendly donation to your email. paypal said you will have to make a account with your email if for some reason you don't have one set up under that email. i noticed though, when the LI collapses, it does not resize the column up. ie. when the expand all collapses, it leaves the columns expanded. would you be able to help me with that last piece? i just saw your last comment... i'd say its a point in the right direction for anyone who is looking for a 'similar' solution.

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close, the problem exists in where you're using .text() to set the link.

```
$(this).text($(this).text().prev() == 'Click to Collapse');
```

That line of code attempts to set the text on $(this) with the return of `$(this).text().prev() == 'Click to Collapse');`

`$(this).text()` returns the string "Click to Collapse".

`.prev()` is not a valid function on strings, thus will result in a javascript error.

What you want to do is `$(this).text("Click to Expand");`

The end result will be something like this:

```
$('.swap').click(function()
            {
                if($(this).text() == 'Click to Collapse')
                {
                    $('ul.menu li ul').slideToggle('normal');
                $('ul.menu li a').removeClass('active');
                    $(this).text('Click to Expand');
                }else{
                    $('ul.menu li ul').slideToggle('normal');
                $('ul.menu li a').addClass('active');
                    $(this).text('Click to Collapse');
                    }
            }
    );
```

Comment: here's the updated code: http://www.jsbin.com/ucobo3/5 i did what you suggested, but i made 'Click to Expand' be within the else statement and the accordion will expand all, but the text does not swap to say 'collapse all' and the link no longer works when i click it now. if i did it the way you suggested, the menu will bounce and close on itself here as seen here: http://www.jsbin.com/ucobo3/4

Comment: Check your javascript, you bound the .swap click four times in a row.  Move it outside of your initMenu call.  You'll have to modify it slightly as well, but this should solve the problem.